# Declaring variables in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, foreach

I have a Tikz graph of a step function which I'm trying to draw, and I think most of it is boiler-plate, but the part that I wrote which isn't working as I'd hoped is:

```
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} 
    \draw[domain=(\i*0.5):((\i+1)*0.5),variable=\x] plot ({\x},{\i*2/5})
    node[right] at (((\i+1)*0.5), (\i*2/5)) {$v=\i \cdot 2/5$};
```

When the last line, `node[right]...` is removed, it draws as expected, but when this line is included, it breaks things.

The puzzling thing to me is that I wrote this for-loop to abstract a previous implementation where I wrote each line individually.  When the lines were written individually, this `node[right]...` stuff did work!  So I'm not sure what about abstracting it into a for-loop caused it to break.

---

Anyway, my main guess as to what is going wrong is something to do with how Tikz is grouping expressions.  So I figured I might be able to fix this by simply declaring a variable `\j` set equal to `\i+1` and then perhaps it this will help it to track what is where in the expression better.  But after a bit of googling I haven't seen anyone explain how to declare variables in Tikz or more specifically inside of a foreach loop.

---

If it helps, though, here is the rest of the drawing:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1.5,yscale=4]
\draw [very thin, gray!30, step=0.5cm] grid (3.9,2.1);
\draw [thick] [->] (-0.2,0)--(4.2,0) node[right, below] {$t$};
\foreach \x in {0.5,...,3.5}
    \draw[xshift=\x cm, thick] (0pt,-1pt)--(0pt,1pt) node[yshift=-0.5cm] {$\x$};

\draw [thick] [->] (0,-0.2)--(0,2.2) node[above, left] {$v$};

\foreach \y in {0,0.5,...,2}
    \draw[yshift=\y cm, thick] (-1pt,0pt)--(1pt,0pt) node[left] {$\y$};

% \draw [domain=0:0.5, variable=\x] plot ({\x}, {0}) node[below right] at (0.4,0.15) {$v=0$};
% The above, in the comment, isn't quite right but it's an example of something that works when not abstracted into the foreach below.  

\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} 
    \draw[domain=(\i*0.5):((\i+1)*0.5),variable=\x] plot ({\x},{\i*2/5})
    node[right] at (((\i+1)*0.5), (\i*2/5)) {$v=\i \cdot 2/5$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this code solve your problem:

```
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{\i*2/5} % <-- added to declare the \j variable
        \draw[domain=(\i*0.5):((\i+1)*0.5),variable=\x] plot ({\x},{\j})
        node[right] () {$v=\j$};
        }
```

Comment: In any case is more cool if you write: \foreach \i in {1,...,5}

Comment: Not that it matters to pgfmath.  All numbers are lengths rendered as strings.